# Qt transparent widgets

Tags: qt, overlay, widget, transparent

Just a quick question.

I'm building my app interface at the moment with Qt.
I set a background image for the mainpage and I use stackedWIdgets to slide from one window to another.

```
setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/spherebackground.png);"
                        "background-repeat: no-repeat;"
                        "background-position: center center");
```

When the application starts, a page appears which is made of 3 layouts:

1) One that contains a topToolbar Widget with QPushButtons, and a label displaying the PageTitle
2) in the middle, a mainPageLayout that contains the SlidingStackedWidgets
3) the BottomToolBar

The mainFrameWidget contains a mainFrameLayout:

mainPageWidget=new QWidget();

mainPageLayout=new QVBoxLayout();

```
//I add the buttons and others
mainPageLayout->addWidget(addEntryButton);
mainPageLayout->addWidget(vocaButton);
mainPageLayout->addWidget(exprButton);
mainPageLayout->addWidget(rulesButton);
mainPageLayout->addWidget(learnButton); 

mainPageWidget->setLayout(mainPageLayout);
```

Then, I have the other pages created with the designer

And then a function that add the pages to the slidingStacked

```
 void MainWindow::createSlidingStackedWidget() {
 //the slidingStacked is the Widget that contains the subslidingWidgets

 slidingStacked= new SlidingStackedWidget(this);
 slidingStacked->addWidget(mainPageWidget);
 quickAddView = new QuickAddController(); //which is a UI widget
 slidingStacked->addWidget(quickAddView);

 }
```

And then, when a button in the mainLayout is pressed, it triggers a function like this

```
void MainWindow::slideInAdd(){
topToolBar->clear();
slidingStacked->setVerticalMode(true);
slidingStacked->slideInIdx(1);
setupTopToolBar("Terminer","Ajout Entrée","Modifier");
bottomToolBar->hide();
QObject::connect(goBackButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(backFromAdd()));
}
```

The thing is that I'm trying to port an application I created for the IPhone and I want it to have the same "Look and Feel" but when I slide from one page to another...

1) the animation flickers
2) I would like the sliding widgets to be transparent except for the controls (QPushButtons...) 
   but they have the same sphere background as the one I set up at the beginning of the code
3) My labels and controls also have the same background image when I would like them to be standard
(eg : a label should have a white background)

I can't figure out why...

Hope this will give you a better idea of what's going on...

Comment: Mike, can you post more of your code so we can understand how you are structuring your stacked widgets, and what widgets you are applying the stylesheet to.

Comment: @Jordan : Here you are, more code. Hope it will help you understand.

Answer (score 0):

So far as 2) and 3) go, that is because widgets inherit their parent's palette by default.  To fix this, you can explicitly style them, or assign their palette to be the default application palette after they are created.  I don't know how to handle the first problem.

Comment: "or assign their palette to be the default application palette after they are created". Could you let me know what this looks like in code please ? I'm new to Qt and I don't know how to do that ? Thanks for your help.